# Android Studio on mac : cant find System compiler

Tags: java, android, macos, compiler-construction, gradle

Im getting this on one of my macs  when I try to compile even "hello world"

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
>
> Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory.

On my other mac, I dont have any problems. The setup is the same as far as I can tell.  It's just that for some reason, on one machine, Android Studio / Gradle pops this error message.

I have set

> JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home

running **/usr/libexec/java_home** gives:

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home

running **javac -version**   gives :

> javac 1.7.0_60-ea

running **java -version**    gives:

> java version "1.7.0_60-ea"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-ea-b15)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)

In Android Studio I have set **file->other settings->default project settings-> JDK location** to  the JDK location listed above.

I've run out of options, why am I still getting this message?

thanks for any help, Ive wasted hours on this already.

Answer (score 2):

My findings from an identical error proved to be due to a clash of Java Jar files that were not related with the Android studio install.
Specifically the tools.jar and auskey.jar under /Library/Java/Extensions 
More info [here](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/mac_gradle_issues_with_finding_using_jdk_7_the_usual_answers_to_this_question_arent_working_expert_required)

Answer (score 1):

Rich_LogicBox solution also worked for me.
I've struggled for weeks with different java versions making no difference.
When I removed the jar files placed in /Library/Java/Extensions by auskey, the Android Studio error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is :

**The android studio needs the `jdk 1.6+` by default, but your `JDK` is 1.7.**

You can `show the package content` of the `Android Studio`in `Applications` folder, and the open the `info.plist`, change the `JVM version` to your JDK's version, which is **1.7*** here.

(you see, my JDK version is 1.8 in my computer)

[image]